# Uncaught TypeError: 'ownKeys' on proxy: trap result did not include 'length'

Tags: ecmascript-6

as header above, I have a code here, try to trap array and when I loop keys of proxy-array object, it gives me a error.

```
    //random array
    let userinfo = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    
    //trap own keys
    userinfo = new Proxy(userinfo,{
        ownKeys(target){
            return Object.keys(target).filter(item=> item>2)
        }
    })
    
    for(let key in userinfo){  //cause error
        console.log(key)
    }
```

Comment: I'll just throw out additionally that Proxy is almost never the right thing to use and this code terrifies me from a complexity and maintainability standpoint.

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: Hi, I want to know, what does this error message mean. And, why I get such error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys` will not return everything `ownKeys` expects because it will omit symbol keys and importantly for things case it will include non-enumerable properties. You need to at a minimum do

```
ownKeys(target){
    return Reflect.ownKeys(target).filter(key => {
        const numKey = +key;
        return Number.isNaN(numKey) || numKey > 2;
    });
}
```

To spell that out, your code has two primary issues:

1. `ownKeys` and `Object.keys` return different things

   - `Object.keys([1,2,3])` => `[ '0', '1', '2' ]`
   - `Reflect.ownKeys([1,2,3])` => `[ '0', '1', '2', 'length' ]`
2. `.filter(item=> item>2)` assumes that all keys will be numeric, and `'length' > 2` returns `false` so your filter would have removed `length` from the array incorrectly. You should only remove numeric keys <= 2.

Comment: Hi loganfsmyth, many many thanks, I get result I want by copying your code. It seems that I got this error because there is key name "length" missed when I do ownKeys(). But, I still don't exactly know what happened inside. Did we exclude the "length" key out of filter result? or did we include "length" key in the filter result so that the result could be enumerable.

Comment: @feeco Updated a little. You need to make sure that `length` is included and not filtered out.